# Is there any semantical difference between element property syntax and atrribute property syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, exception

I thought that element property syntax and attribute property syntax have no big semantical difference. However, I found that there must be some difference.

E.g. The following example just demonstrates a simple trigger:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Button><Button.Template>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="hello" Text="Hello" />
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" TargetName="hello"/>
     </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template></Button>
</Page>
```

However, if I used a element property syntax for property `Property` of trigger, it throws an exception saying that setter! (not trigger) requires both property and value.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Button><Button.Template>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="hello" Text="Hello" />
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Value="True">
        <Trigger.Property>IsMouseOver</Trigger.Property>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" TargetName="hello"/>
     </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template></Button>
</Page>
```

So, what is the *hidden* difference between element property syntax and attribute property syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a difference.  I think you just found a bug in the XAML parser.

The framework has special handling for Setter, Trigger, and Condition.  Check out [Trigger.ReceiveTypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.receivetypeconverter.aspx) with Reflector, which overrides the handling of property setters for the Value and Property properties.  I think this is so that it can parse the Value property with a different type based on the Property property.  For example, it parses "Red" as a Brush rather than just a String when it sees the Property is Foreground and that Foreground is of type Brush.

It looks like that hook overrides all sets of properties named Value or Property within a Trigger, but that it doesn't correctly handle the element property syntax.  To see the effect, try creating a markup extension like this:

```
public class Test
    : MarkupExtension
{
    public DependencyProperty Property { get; set; }
    public DependencyProperty Property2 { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Property ?? Property2;
    }
}
```

The following XAML will get the same error as your second example, and you can verify by setting a breakpoint that Property is never set:

```
<Trigger.Property>
    <local:Test>
        <local:Test.Property>IsMouseOver</local:Test.Property>
    </local:Test>
</Trigger.Property>
```

However, this will work, because the property is not named "Property":

```
<Trigger.Property>
    <local:Test>
        <local:Test.Property2>IsMouseOver</local:Test.Property2>
    </local:Test>
</Trigger.Property>
```

And this will work, because it uses the attribute syntax:

```
<Trigger.Property>
    <local:Test Property="IsMouseOver"/>
</Trigger.Property>
```

If you really need to use the element property syntax, that will give you a workaround: create a MarkupExtension that has a Property of type DependencyProperty named something other than "Property", and return that in ProvideValue.